# Efficiently splitting strings

Tags: string, performance, lua, split

As a result of log parsing I have a field that contains hostnames and occasionally IP addresses. I need to further process the data in that field to parse domains from the hostnames. I.e. if the hostname is googleanalytics.google.com I want to parse google.com from it as efficiently as possible, as the system processes thousands of log messages per second.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
-- Save hostname into a temporary variable
local tempMetaValue = hostname

local count = 0
local byte_char = string.byte(".")
for i = 1, #tempMetaValue do
    if string.byte(tempMetaValue, i) == byte_char then
        count = count + 1
    end
end

local dotCount = count

-- If there was only one dot do nothing
if dotCount == 1 then
    return 0

-- Check whether there were more than one dot
elseif dotCount == 2 then
    -- Get the index of the first dot
    local beginIndex = string.find(tempMetaValue,".",1,true)
    -- Get the substring starting after the first dot
    local domainMeta = string.sub(tempMetaValue,beginIndex+1)
    -- Double check that the substring exists
    if domainMeta ~= nil then
        -- Populate the domain meta field
    end
-- If there are more than two dots..
elseif dotCount > 2 then
    -- Test to see if the hostname is actually an IP address
    if tempMetaValue:match("%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?%.%d%d?%d?") then
        -- Skip the rest if an IP address was found
    end
    -- Get the index of the second to last dot
    local beginIndex = string.find(tempMetaValue,"\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$")
    -- Get the substring starting after the second to last dot
    local domainMeta = string.sub(tempMetaValue,beginIndex+1)
    -- Double check that the substring exists
    if domainMeta ~= nil then
        -- Populate the domain meta field
    end
end
```

I have a feeling though that his might no be the fastest possible solution. "A feeling" because before this I have had zero experience in Lua, but it seems awfully long for such a simple task.

I tried creating a solution where an operation similar to split in e.g. Java would be performed and where it would leave the last token "unsplit", thus leaving me with the part (domain) I actually want, but got nowhere with those attempts. So basically for that solution I would want to create as many tokens as there are dots in the hostname value, i.e. googleanalytics.google.com would be split into "googleanalytics" and "google.com".

Comment: If you are asking for general "how can I make my code better" response then this is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Just for the record.

Comment: For ways to split strings in lua look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this do what you want?

```
function getdomain(str)
    -- Grad just the last two dotted parts of the string.
    local domain = str:match("%.?([^.]+%.[^.]+)$")
    -- If we have dotted parts and they are all numbers then this is an IP address.
    if domain and tonumber((domain:gsub("%.", ""))) then
        return nil
    end
    return domain
end

print(getdomain("googleanalytics.google.com"))
print(getdomain("foobar.com"))
print(getdomain("1.2.3.4"))
print(getdomain("something.else.longer.than.that.com"))
print(getdomain("foobar"))
```

That "is it an IP address" test is incredibly stupid and should quite likely be made a more robust test but for the quick demo that serves.

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly is completely from a different world compared to what I had before.